# Mostrar divs según variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs

Soy bastante novato en Vue y además vengo de jQuery y la verdad es que siento que tengo que cambiar mi mentalidad totalmente porque no tienen nada que ver.

Quiero aprender a hacer algo muy simple, tener 5 divs y que el primero se muestre y los otros 4 no. La idea es que quiero añadir 2 botones ("Pág anterior" y "Pag siguiente") y quiero que se vaya mostrando un div u otro según vaya pulsando (tipo paginador, pero no quiero paginar datos de un array/objeto sino cambiar de vista). Esto en jquery lo hago en un segundo pero aquí mi mentalidad no me permite hacerlo jejeje.

Tengo planteado lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.pagina_activa
{
    display:block;
}

.pagina_noactiva
{
    display:none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="app">

    <figure v-for="i in 5" :class="[(paginaActual == i) ? 'pagina_activa' : 'pagina_noactiva']">

        <h3>Página {{i}}</h3>

    </figure>

    <hr>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="cambiarPagina('sumar')">Página Anterior</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="cambiarPagina('restar')">Página Siguiente</button>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:
    {
        paginaActual: 1,
    },
    methods:
    {
        cambiarPagina(valPag)
        {
            if(valPag == "sumar")
            {
                this.paginaActual++;
            }

            else
            {
                this.paginaActual--;
            }
        }
    }
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Necesito saber cómo se debe hacer en Vue, porque mirando por internet creo que puedo sacarlo...pero creo que no voy a escirbir el código que Vue merece. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Lo que veo es que si le doy clic en "Página siguiente" el valor de i comienza a ser restado en 1. Tal vez lo que quieres hacer para el botón de página siguiente es aumentarlo en 1, y cuando se esté en la última página desactivarlo. 
Para el caso de "Página anterior", quizá lo que debes hacer es restarlo hasta se esté visualizando la página 1 (indice cero). ¿es algo así lo que quieres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo tenías casi listo, el valPag que le pasas al metodo cambiarPagina lo estas haciendo al revés. Además faltaba agregar una validacion que no pueda bajar de 1 o pasar de 5, y de yapa agrega siempre .prevent en los eventos, especialmente los que pueden provocar postbacks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .pagina_activa {
            display: block;
        }

        .pagina_noactiva {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">

        <figure v-for="i in 5" :class="[(paginaActual == i) ? 'pagina_activa' : 'pagina_noactiva']">

            <h3>Página {{i}}</h3>

        </figure>

        <hr>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="cambiarPagina('restar')">Página Anterior</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="cambiarPagina('sumar')">Página Siguiente</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:
            {
                paginaActual: 1,
            },
            methods:
            {
                cambiarPagina(valPag) {
                    if (valPag === "sumar") {
                        if (this.paginaActual === 5) return;
                        this.paginaActual++;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (this.paginaActual === 1) return;
                        this.paginaActual--;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Buah! El tema es que la validación me daba igual porque estaba centrado en hacer que cambiara de página... y lo que me pasaba realmente es que tenía el valor de restar en sumar y viceversa...así que cuando probaba y le daba a siguiente se quedaba en blanco y pensé que no funcionaba... Gracias por la ayuda! Tendré en cuenta todo lo que me has comentado ;)